# Global minimum of sum of exponentials

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, exponential-function, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Given $n$ functions, $f_i$ $(i=1,\dots,n)$ all of which are in the same function form of $\vec{x}$ but different coefficients in the exponent

$$f_i(\vec{x}) = \exp \left( \sum_{j=1}^m c_{ij} x_j \right)$$

Is there a way to determine the global minimum of

$$F=\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(\vec{x})$$

In an efficient manner for large number of unknowns? It seems that there is a lot of symmetry which could be exploited, especially since $F$ is sum of similar expressions. (In our problem set-up there always exists an unique global solution)

Illustrative Example:
$$f_1 = \exp(+.5 x_0 - 2 x_1) \\
f_2 = \exp(+.5 x_0 - 1 x_1) \\
f_3 = \exp(-.5 x_0 + 5 x_1)\\
f_4 = \exp(-.5 x_0 - 5 x_1)$$

With $F=f_1+f_2+f_3+f_4$ has global minimum at $\vec{x}=\{0.137532, 0.0612319\}$.

Hoping there might be some symmetry tricks, or iterative procedures than can be used; currently for small scale problems using Newton's Method for numerical solving which produces $m*m$ matrix for Hessians.

Comment: Which is the problem setup that always give solutions? For sure there are many cases in which there is no minima (just take all coefficients associated to the same variable with the same sign).

Comment: In Maximum Entropy (loglinear) models the optimization can be rephrased as minimizing log(Z) - dot(L,c)  where Z is the partition function, L is the Lagrange multipliers and c is the constraints they should satisfy. If you take the exponent and simplify it reduces minimizing the sum of exponential terms.